# Best book on Sequences and Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am reaffirming my familiarity of this topic.  I didn't find that this question has been asked yet.

After reading Dantzig's book "Numbers", I became more interested in this area of analysis.  I originally studied it a long time ago.  So what are the community recommendations?   I seek more proper, complete, comprehensive treatments.  Also, I'd like it to be more exclusively on this topic.

Comment: I like Theory and Application of Infinite Series by Konrad Knopp, personally. It has a lot of good exercises and is fairly comprehensive in its treatment.

Comment: A compilation of lots of series problems (but it also has some other stuff in the mix) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thanks!   I'll look into that!

Comment: I also would like to vouch for Knopp. It was my first real analysis book, and I thoroughly enjoyed it.

Comment: (Btw, that PDF was made by a MSE user, and unless you knew Italian, this year's edition is the first in English)

Comment: And I would always recommend Mike Spivak's *Calculus* as a wonderful text on analysis on $\Bbb R$. Lots of fabulous stuff in the sequences and series chapters.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Spivak seems like the most highly recommended book on calc.  Duly noted.   However I am seeking books exclusive to series.

Comment: If you're being totally exclusive (for reasons I don't totally understand, since you need more broad-ranging techniques to deal with series), Knopp is the way to go.

Comment: @Ted Indeed, they both deal with the infinite and there's the good old integral test involved.   I just feel like compartmentalizing things I'm not as solid in. A book dealing in something I'm not as confident in seems more direct, relations to derivatives and integrals aside.

Comment: Bromwich's *Infinite Series* was one of the first "modern" books on series in English. Highly influential, possibly worth a look (you may find the style a bit strange, but that's not necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: @Chappers thank you,  I'm all about seeing things from different angles

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt that PDF is pretty neat but also quite advanced. I hope to work my way up there after I reaffirm the basics.

Comment: Heh, I agree. I'm working my way very slowly through the thing, skipping whatever flies over my head.

Comment: @Chappers I was thrilled to see Bromwich referenced so heavily in Hardy' s A Course in Pure Mathematics

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate Hardy has very high praise for it in his obituary of Bromwich, which can be read [here](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/129/811/0.full.pdf). (in particular p. vi, 9 in the PDF): "It has two supreme merits, rare indeed in English text-books  of its time ; it is thoroughly interesting,  and the detailed analysis is almost always sound and clear. Whatever one may think of the  general  scheme, individual  sections  are hardly ever obscure. [...]

Comment: [...] Finally, among  all treatises  on infinite series, this  book stands by itself as a work of reference and a storehouse of information ; it really is “ a book that no mathematician can do without.”" My impression is that it was a pretty significant influence on Hardy (I wonder if it was one of the inspirations for writing the *Course* in the first place).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Ted Shifrin on Spivak's *Calculus* as a strong book on sequences and series (and he should know,he wrote most of the exercises for it from the second edition onwards.......lol) .

Most elementary analysis texts contains chapters on sequences and series, but most of the best sources on the subject are the older pre-Rudin analysis texts. One of my favorites is sadly long out of print-it's W. Ferrar's *A Textbook of Convergence*. If you can locate a copy of this forgotten classic, you definitely should do so. Another very good source along these lines is Titchmarsh's *Theory of Functions*,which also contains excellent classical treatments of measure theory and complex variables.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/Convergence_78 It's indeed a very nice piece

Comment: Downloaded!   Thank you

Comment: Nice recommendations of older texts!

Comment: All hail Spivak

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy I think Spivak is somewhat overrated. It's a very good book for introducing a rigorous approach to single-variable analysis, but the APPLICATIONS of calculus are just as important as the foundations. If you're only talking about the careful foundations,then you've got an ANALYSIS book-NOT a calculus book. Not that that's a bad thing,mind you. But it's kind of like going to a renowned Italian restaurant and being served a fantastic homemade burger and fresh cut fries. It's not bad,but not really what was advertised,right?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 shhhhhh.... don't say anything critical about Spivak on this website, it's not worth it.   Kidding aside, id take that burger one night and the homemade Italian the next.   But yes I came for the Italian.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy If Spivak had revised the book to include a substantial number of real applications to physics,finance,probability,etc.,we could just get rid of all other rigorous calculus textbooks because we wouldn't need them anymore.